# Hangouts Chat, is there anyway to show prompts in hangouts chat?

Tags: adaptive-cards, google-hangouts

Hi I searched a lot for this,
can we create prompt messages in hangouts chat? So far i can create cards, and the actions can be captured inside `CARD_CLICKED` event.

I need a prompt sort of message to display in hangouts chat so that when a user clicks on it, it should be posted in the chat as the user input.

Or anyway to build custom messages in hangouts bot with html?

Is there anyway to do that or am i going in the wrong direction?

Please help

Comment: The `CARD_CLICKED` action can trigger a bot to send a message of type `user X said Y` but this message will be posted by the bot, not by the user.

Comment: thanks @ziganotschka. i was able to figured that out, and is there any site where we can get the all the different types of card messages?

Comment: Have a look [here](https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/how-tos/cards-onclick).